# MySQL 8.0のコンソールにログインできません。

Tags: mysql

AWS EC2のインスタンスにMySQL8.0のインストールを行い、ログインを試みましたが
不可能でした。

インストールの手順と試したことです。

インストール

```
$ sudo mysql80-community-source MySQL 8.0 Community enabled
$ yum install  mysql-server
```

```
$ systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
```

Checking Status

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-06 11:32:29 JST; 10s ago
```

```
$ sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
2020-05-31T13:56:58.175675Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: ll!.iXg=K4Rr
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
php-mysqlnd-7.4.19-1.amzn2.x86_64
mysql-community-client-8.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
php72-php-mysqlnd-7.2.34-4.el7.remi.x86_64
mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch
mysql-community-common-8.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-server-8.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-8.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
```

こちらの
"ll!.iXg=K4Rr"
を使いましたが
下記のエラーが出ました。
Access denied happnend

Comment: ちょっといけない書き方ですが、`mysql -u root --password=PassWord`でパスワードをべた書きで入力するとどうなりますか？

Comment: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Insescureだと警告されますね・・

Comment: よく見るとsystemctl start mysqldのコマンドの結果がfaildになっているのにstatusはactiveになっていますね。本当にmysqlは起動していますか？またsystemctlはsudoが必要かと思いますが。

Answer (score 0):

1.起動するときに、「Failed to start mysqld.service」が出て、起動失敗だと思いますが、ステータスチェックすると、起動しているのが見えるため、別のMySqlがすでに起動しているかもしれないです。

２．以下の方法でmysqlのパスワードをリセットしてみてください。
/etc/my.cnfの[mysqld]セクションの下に以下の設定を追加する。

```
[mysqld]
.
.
skip-grant-tables
.
.
```

Mysqlを再起動

```
sudo systemctl restart mysqld
```

Mysqlに接続して、rootパスワード再設定する

```
$sudo mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql
mysql>UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('パスワード') WHERE user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

skip-grant-tablesの設定を削除し、もう一回Mysqlを再起動してから、mysql -uroot -pでログインしてみてください。